# Laravel 8 'Route [admin.test] not defined'

Tags: php, laravel, caching, routes

I'm trying to write a new route, but it doesn't work. Even this route is not shown in the route:list. But if i write route:cache, this route is working. It's annoying for each new route, how to solve them ?

```
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'auth', 'as' => 'admin.'], function () {
        Route::get('/test', [AdminIndexController::class, 'index'])->name('test');  
});
```

in blade.php

```
<a href="{{ route('admin.test') }}">Test</a>
```

Comment: The route you defined is named 'test', not 'admin.test' if you want to prefix the name: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-group-name-prefixes

Comment: is it production or local ?

Comment: check route list using "php artisan route:list" command from cli. And try cleaning route cache "php artisan route:clear".

Comment: i use " 'as' => 'admin.' ", if this code was incorrect, it would not work after route:cache

Comment: Oh wait... The problem is you need to clear the cache after creating a new route? Thats one single command.... Whats the problem? Laravel caches the routes to speed up your application.

Comment: it's local, not production

Comment: The problem is that I have not encountered such a problem in previous projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove the routes cache , remove this file:

```
bootstrap/cache/routes.php
```

After that you can run artisan command

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

But There's no problem about not using route cache. It just can make "your route registration up to 100x faster" as noted in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-caching).

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in you Route group:

```
Route::get('/test/create', [AdminIndexController::class, 'create'])->name('test.create');
```

Now your route should look like this

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'auth', 'as' => 'admin.'], function () {
  Route::get('/test', [AdminIndexController::class, 'index'])->name('test'); 
  Route::get('/test/create', [AdminIndexController::class, 'create'])->name('test.create'); 
});
```

thank